# os.exec on Windows

Tags: python, windows, windows-xp, python-3.x, exec

I have a script that calls `os.execvp` into another Python instance. After doing this, I appear to be attached to a `cmd.exe` instance, not the Python instance I just created. The Python instance responds to <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> however.

```
H:\bin>Python 3.2.1 (default, Jul 10 2011, 21:51:15) [MSC v.1500
 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('hi')
Can't find file ('hi')

H:\bin>

H:\bin>
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> echo hi
hi
```

The call to `exec`:

```
from sys import argv
os.execvp('python', argv)
```

How do I replace the original Python instance with the new one, as per the behaviour one might see on Linux?

Comment: Related: http://bugs.python.org/issue9148. According to Amaury Forgeot d'Arc's [comment](http://bugs.python.org/issue9148#msg109179) - *on Windows, `exec()` does not really replace the current process. It creates a new process (with a new pid), and exits the current one. Hence the calling program only sees that the script has terminated. I don't see any easy solution on Windows, except than using `subprocess.Popen()`, and exit the script when the subprocess terminates.* Does it look like a possible solution in your case?

Comment: Thanks for the useful comment @PiotrDobrogost. If you related the material in the Python issue to this question that would constitute a solution.

Comment: You mean like first calling `subprocess.Popen()` and then exiting  from the original Python process?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: Yes, in the interest of people following this same problem, they deserve a clean solution and justification.

Comment: @MattJoiner Hi, I just stumbled into this while trying to port a library to Windows. I am struggling to find a complete, working example based on `subprocess.Popen`. Any idea where I could find one?

Comment: @s-m-e sorry, no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Unix executing binaries is split into two stages - [fork(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fork) to clone current process and [exec(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fork) to load executable into address space. On windows there is only [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which does the same thing as fork+exec.

For portability your best bet is to use [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) (which also does proper filename quoting on Windows unlike os.* counterparts) as in http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-the-os-spawn-family

Comment: Can you link to a mention of the differing `os.exec*` behaviour on Windows? I was under the impression that exec is supported on Windows, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/431x4c1w(v=VS.100).aspx)

Comment: First paragraph in url you posted: "Each function in this family loads and executes a *new* process". In MS CRT they're just wrappers around CreateProcess.

Comment: _When a call to an _exec function is successful, the new process is placed in the memory previously occupied by the calling process. Sufficient memory must be available for loading and executing the new process._ Also after the example exec call, there's a comment `/* This point is reached only if exec fails. */`.

Comment: I suspect that line was copied verbatim from POSIX.1 spec. "This point is reached": see description of any _exec, "Return value" clause. "If successful, these functions do not return to the calling process", they do ExitProcess() call upon sucessful CreateProcess() call iirc.

Comment: For detailed information on how CreateProcess works internally see http://www.scribd.com/doc/51979000/122/Flow-of-CreateProcess

Comment: that line was from the MSDN documentation.