# How to do os.execv() in Python in Windows without detaching from the console?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, exec

I'm using Python 2.6 on Windows 7. I have Windows .cmd file which invokes Python to run the CherryPy Web server (version 3.1.2). I start this .cmd file by executing it at the prompt in a Windows CMD shell. When CherryPy notices that one of its dependent files has changed, it restarts. There are a couple problems that arise in this configuration on Windows, because the invocation that CherryPy uses to restart itself is

```
os.execv(sys.executable, args)
```

but you can't invoke the Python executable on the .cmd file. I've managed to bypass that problem through various Python gymnastics, and now I've got it restarting by calling (essentially)

```
os.execv(sys.argv[0], args)
```

But the restarted process is detached from the keyboard; it will catch Ctrl-C, and then I'm asked

```
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

but the Y or N I type is caught not by the terminating .cmd file, but by the Windows CMD shell, and it responds

```
'Y' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

So how do I set things up in Windows to keep the restarted process in what I'd call "the foreground" in Unix?

Comment: This question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004687/os-exec-on-windows) is a simpler version of this question. An answer to that question would count as an answer to this one, but it hasn't been answered satisfactorily.

Comment: Take a look at my new comment to that question.

Comment: 10 years later - any ideas how to solve this? I am [struggling with same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67371606/1672565) ...

Answer (score -3):

you can use subprocess.call method like this example

```
import subprocess

retcode = subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
```

see this link for more information about subprocess class:

[subprocess — Subprocess management](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: Nope, that has the same defect as the original method.