# How to "replace" `os.execvpe` on Windows efficiently - if the "child" process is an interactive command line application?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, spawn, execvp

I am dealing with a Python script which does, after some preparation work, launch `ssh`. My script is actually a small CLI tool. On Unix-like systems, at the end of its life, the Python script replaces itself with the `ssh` client, so the user can now interact with `ssh` directly (i.e. run arbitrary commands on the remote machine etc):

```py
os.execvpe('ssh', ['ssh', '-o', 'foo', 'user@host'], os.environ)
```

Positive surprise & side-note in case you are wondering: Windows 10 actually has a native version of OpenSSH now built-in, so there is a `ssh` command on this platform.

`os.execvpe` is present in the Python standard library on Windows, but it does not replace the original (Python) process. The situation is ... somewhat complicated: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7004687/1672565), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7264571/1672565), [3](https://bugs.python.org/issue19124). Bottom line: **Windows does not implement the corresponding POSIX semantics for replacing a running process.**

The common wisdom is to use `subprocess.Popen` instead, ok, effectively creating a child process. I can launch the child so that the parent keeps running OR I can launch the child while the parent dies (I *think* that Windows does support the latter just like Unix-like systems). Either way, the user can not interact with the child in the command line.

Assuming that I keep the parent alive, I now have to write a ton of code to pass user I/O to/from the child through the parent, like [so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19880190/1672565) for instance. The latter involves managing streams and even threads, depending on how well it is supposed to behave - a lot of places for potential issues and breakages down the road. I do not like to do this (if I can avoid it).

How can I *efficiently* replace `os.execvpe` on Windows in the described scenario?

---

EDIT (1): Bits and pieces, which may be relevant ...

- [Handle Inheritance I](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/handle-inheritance)
- [Handle Inheritance II](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/win32/procthread/inheritance)
- [STARTUPINFO in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfoa)
- [STARTUPINFO in Windows - for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.STARTUPINFO)

I guess it depends on figuring out how to correctly configure a `STARTUPINFO` object before passing it into `Popen`. A command line can in fact be *inherited* in Windows.

---

EDIT (2): A partial solution via `pywin32` - `ssh` opens into a second, new `cmd` window and can be interacted with. The original shell with Python remains open, Python itself quits:

```py
from win32.Demos.winprocess import Process
from shlex import join
Process(join(['ssh', '-o', 'foo', 'user@host']))
```

Comment: You might want to check https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable.

Comment: @CristiFati Wrapping `ssh` in `expect` - it's a variation of "manually" passing through all user I/O. At the end of the day, it is still rather complicated, but thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

A **partial and incomplete** solution looks about as follows, see **TODO comments**:

```py
import win32api, win32process, win32con
from shlex import join

si = win32process.STARTUPINFO()

# TODO fix flags
si.dwFlags = win32con.STARTF_USESTDHANDLES ^ win32con.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW

# inherit stdin, stdout and stderr
si.hStdInput = win32api.GetStdHandle(win32api.STD_INPUT_HANDLE)
si.hStdOutput = win32api.GetStdHandle(win32api.STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
si.hStdError = win32api.GetStdHandle(win32api.STD_ERROR_HANDLE)

# TODO fix value?
si.wShowWindow = 1

# TODO set values?
# si.dwX, si.dwY = ...
# si.dwXSize, si.dwYSize = ...
# si.lpDesktop = ...

procArgs = (
    None,  # appName
    join(['ssh', '-o', 'foo', 'user@host']),  # commandLine
    None,  # processAttributes
    None,  # threadAttributes
    1,  # bInheritHandles TODO ?
    win32process.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,  # dwCreationFlags
    None,  # newEnvironment
    None,  # currentDirectory
    si, # startupinfo
)

procHandles = win32process.CreateProcess(*procArgs) # run ...
```

`ssh` opens into a second, new `cmd.exe` window and can be interacted with. The original `cmd.exe` window with Python in it remains open, Python itself quits, returning control to `cmd.exe` itself. It is usable, although inconsistent and ugly.

I guess it comes down to configuring `win32process.STARTUPINFO` correctly, but even after heaving read tons of documentation on it, I am somehow failing to make sense of it ...

Answer (score -2):

You can use `subprocess.Popen` or or `subprocess.call`  function instead of `os.execvpe`. They have flag `shell` which ensures that child process can get `stdin`.
I have tried in windows using following code:

```
import os
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('ssh -o foo user@host', shell=True, env=os.environ)
```

And it works.

Comment: @s-m-e, can you elaborate, is there something I missed in question?

Comment: I want to launch `ssh` so a user can *interactively* use it. My Python script runs in the command line. So does `ssh`. `ssh` is supposed to *inherit* the command line from the Python process so a user can actually *interact* with `ssh`. Your suggestion launches `ssh`, but it does not turn control over to it. Instead, it dies in the background together with my Python script.