# Python os.execlp() in Cygwin returns different child pid

Tags: python, python-3.x, cygwin, exec

In Cygwin, calling Python3 `os.execlp()` creates a new process to run external python codes, child's pid is different from that returned by previous `os.fork()`.

I do not know why Cygwin have this weird result.

---

Running Environment :

- Cygwin under win10
- Python 3.6.4

Code :

*parent.py*

```
pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
     os.execlp('python', 'python', 'child.py')
else:
     print('child is , ', pid)
```

*child.py*

```
print(os.getpid())
```

When running parent code in Cygwin, the pid numbers returned by two `print` function are different.

```
# running result $python fork-exec.py
Child is  6104
Hello from child,  9428
```

This program runs perfectly under Linux platform.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's start by stating that being a native Unix/Linux system primitive, `fork` hasn't any equivalent in Windows, and `os.fork` doesn't exist in Windows native python for that very reason.

But, Python built for Cygwin is able to make it available because Cygwin emulates `fork` ([how to run python script with os.fork on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300551/how-to-run-python-script-with-os-fork-on-windows))

Now, the actual reason why PIDs are different is that `os.execlp` doesn't behave the same on Windows or on Linux. On windows, `execlp` is also an emulation and does NOT replace the current process. It just spawns a new process using `CreateProcess` underneath. Cygwin is able to emulate `fork` properly, but not `exec`.

So `fork+exec` is replaced by `CreateProcess` on Windows ([os.exec on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004687/os-exec-on-windows)), and `os.exec` *does* create a new process, hence the different PIDs.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and the links. It is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

the PID is diffrent because cygwin hosts one of them, which is already a process. and windows handles PID's diffrently than most linux distro's.